# How to check if a dump-generated backup is OK?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, backup, dump

When dumping my FS with `dump`, e.g.:

```
$ dump -0f /path/to/usb/nonexistant-file-name /
```

I get a binary file, extension-free. It's normal.
I regularly store such backups, if ever I need to restore one. As usual.
But...

How can I check the reliability of such a file produced by `dump`? How can I check if it's globally correct, to be sure it's restorable?
I cannot test IRL by recovering my own working system, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the backup with the current contents of the system using `restore`:

```
restore -C -f backup
```

where `backup` is the file containing your backup.

You can also list the contents of a backup:

```
restore -t -f backup
```

Answer (score 1):

The Default restore directory is /tmp
With the option -T u can specify another directory.

U can read more about restore.
http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_restore.htm